# Plesk + Phusion Passenger: core-js npm install fails - "npm ERR! sh: node: command not found"

Tags: node.js, npm, passenger, plesk, core-js

I am installing node (version 17.3.0) on a Plesk-managed server. I am just one of many users of this server, I have no superuser password and the nodejs app is supposed to run in a subdomain I manage.

I am following the instructions from [this sample page](https://www.plesk.com/blog/product-technology/node-js-plesk-onyx/). The failing phase is the installation of dependencies through NPM.

The log contains the following, relevant lines:

```
npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.12: core-js@<3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js@3.
...
...
...
npm ERR! code 127
npm ERR! path /var/......../sandbox/helloworld/node_modules/core-js
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"
npm ERR! sh: node: command not found
```

(I don't believe the warning is really crucial, because I've seen it before in situations not leading to a failure.)

Obviously the node executable is not in my $PATH, but this installation is managed (as far as I understand) by Phusion Passenger. **I need to know where the nodejs executable is deployed**, so that I can add it to my $PATH.

I am using the last available version for every dependency.

Comment: try this command : `which node` ... That command should tell you where `node` is at.

Comment: @MattOestreich - Come on! I just wrote that node is NOT on my `$PATH` because it is not installed by me. How can you dream of finding it with `which`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to find a workaround for this issue.

In [this page](https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000644114-Node-js-Run-Script-option-fails-on-Plesk-server-no-node-binary-in-the-current-PATH) they suggest to put a record `scripts-prepend-node-path=true` inside [.npmrc](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/configuring-npm/npmrc).

This solved the problem. As a nice side effect, I am now able to read in logs where node is installed: `/opt/plesk/node/<MAJOR_VERSION_NUMBER>/bin`.
I put it here while I modify the question title because this is most probably a Plesk installation/configuration pattern.